JWT token valid in Postman but invalid in mobile app authentication
Here's a comprehensive body that incorporates the key points and potential troubleshooting steps:
I'm having trouble authenticating users in my mobile app using JWT tokens generated by a Node.js backend. The token generation and validation seem to work correctly when tested using Postman, but the mobile app consistently rejects the token as invalid.
Backend (Node.js):
const loginUser = async (req, res) => {
  const { username, password } = req.body;
  try {
    const user = await User.findOne({ username })
        .populate('address', 'street reference city state postalCode coordinates isDefault');

    if (!user) {
      return res.status(400).json({ message: 'Usuário não corresponde' });
    }

    const isMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);

    if (!isMatch) {
      return res.status(400).json({ message: 'Senha inválida' });
    }

    const token = generateToken(user);

    // Converter o documento do Mongoose em um objeto JS
    const userObj = user.toObject();
    delete userObj.password; // Remover o campo password

    res.json({ data: userObj, token });
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
    res.status(500).send('Erro no servidor');
  }
};

const generateToken = (user) => {
  return jwt.sign({ id: user._id, role: user.role }, process.env.JWT_SECRET, { expiresIn: process.env.JWT_EXPIRES_IN });
};

const verifyToken = (token) => {
  return jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET);
};

authMiddleware.js
const authMiddleware = async (req, res, next) => {
  const token = req.header('Authorization')?.replace('Bearer ', ''); 
  if (!token) {
    return res.status(401).json({ message: 'Acesso negado. Nenhum token fornecido.' });
  }

  try {
    const decoded = jwtUtil.verifyToken(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET);

    req.user = await User.findById(decoded.id).select('-password');

    if (!req.user) {
      return res.status(404).json({ message: 'Usuário não encontrado' });
    }
    next();
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Algo deu errado com a verificação de token:', err.message);
    res.status(401).json({ message: 'Token não é válido' });
  }
};

const verifyAndAuthorization = (req, res, next) => {
  authMiddleware(req, res, () => {
    if (req.user.role === "Admin" || req.user.role === "Manager" || req.user.role === "Vendor" || req.user.role === "Customer" || req.user.role === "Delivery") {
      next()
    } else {
      res.status(403).json({ msg: "Você não tem autorização para acessar esta rota." })
    }
  })
}

Mobile App (Dart/Flutter):
Future<void> sendLogin() async {
    try {
      if (formKeyLorgin.currentState?.saveAndValidate() ?? false) {
        final username = formKeyLorgin.currentState?.fields['username']?.value;
        final password = formKeyLorgin.currentState?.fields['password']?.value;
        final response = await _authRepository.login(username, password);
        userData.value = UserModel.fromJson(response);
        String user = jsonEncode(response['data']);
        String token = jsonEncode(response['token']);
        log(user);
        _storageService
          ..box.write('user', user)
          ..saveLogged(isLogged.value)
          ..saveToken(token);
        log(token);
        Get.offAndToNamed('/home');
      } else {}
    } catch (e) {
      SnackbarService.showErrorMessage('$e');
      log("Erro: $e", error: e);
    }
  }

Troubleshooting Steps:
Token Structure: I've verified that the token structure and payload are identical in both Postman and the mobile app.
Time Synchronization: I've ensured that the server and device clocks are synchronized to avoid issues with token expiration.
HTTP Headers: I've checked that the HTTP headers, especially the Authorization header, are set correctly in both environments.
Network Requests: I've inspected the network requests using developer tools to look for any discrepancies or errors.
Token Storage: I've tried storing the token in different ways (e.g., secure storage, shared preferences) on the device to rule out storage-related issues.
Additional Information:
Device and OS: [Specify the device and OS]
Mobile App Framework: Flutter/dart
JWT Library: jsonwebtoken
Network Environment: local, with NGROK and without.
Database: Atlas MongoDB

What error do you get? Did you try adding debug logs on the backend and check if you are getting the required data?

I don't know what the generateToken function returns. My guess is that it returns a token string. So res.json({ data: userObj, token }); seems to be wrong. Have you tried returning res.json({ data: userObj, token: token }); like this?

Sorry, I added the generateToken and verifyToken functions. The tokens, as I mentioned above, are working 'well'. However, this issue only occurs on the mobile device. I captured the generated token and tested it in Postman, where it worked perfectly. The headers are also set to application/json.
